# How do I organize my huge set of serializers in Django Rest Framework (DRF)?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have large project and many serializers in serializer.py. How I can structure my project? All serializers used in unique endpoint. Maybe I must to split my serializers.py?

Comment: First, split your large project into different apps. Try not to have all your project code in a single app. again there you can split your serializers based on your model.

Answer (score 0):

In Django rest projects you import serializers in other files like views.py. You have to create a directory and create multiple files for your serializers. Organize them by resource their using (e.x. Product, Category, and so on) or by the needs of your project. When they are in different directories and subdirectories with proper names they are well organized. Also, you can import them easily.